# How do I solve the - ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'gekko', in spyder?

Tags: python, gekko

I have installed the gekko package and have updated pip to its latest version. I have run the 'pip list' command and confirmed that the gekko package is installed. In fact, I can use the gekko package with the **sublime editor** on the same machine with the same script but the same script throws the `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'gekko'` error when I try to run it in a **spyder editor**. I have python versions 3.6 and 3.9 installed and running on windows 10.

Comment: You need to ensure that the python version your running is the same python version you used pip to install gekko with.

Comment: You may find this helpful: https://docs.spyder-ide.org/current/faq.html#using-existing-environment

Comment: If you installed Spyder via Anaconda, the interpreter will use a separate installation of python by default.

Comment: Going through the Docs and FAQs through that link really helped. Thanks @Ghoti

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to the great suggestion by @Ghoti to change to another Python version in Spyder, it is also easy to install `gekko` on another version such as the distribution that comes with an Anaconda install. An easy way to find Python distributions is to run `which python` or `which python3` from the command line.

```sh
john@aps:~/Desktop$ which python3
/usr/bin/python3
```

When you find the correct path to the distribution, try the following with the correct absolute path:

```sh
/usr/bin/python3 -m pip install gekko
```

Many don't use the system python in `/usr/bin/` but will create a [virtual environment](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html) with `venv` or similar method to maintain separate python installations. If you have an Anaconda distribution then you can start an Anaconda prompt and try `pip` or `pip3` to install gekko.

```sh
pip install gekko
```

The following isn't the recommended method (actively discouraged) to use pip in a script:

```py
try:
    from pip import main as pipmain
except:
    from pip._internal import main as pipmain
pipmain(['install','gekko'])
# to upgrade: pipmain(['install','--upgrade','gekko'])
```

Comment: Excellent contribution there @John Hedengren.