# Gekko not found in Spyder

Tags: spyder, gekko

I am new to python. I have a windows machine. I installed python and am using it with vs code. All packages including gekko work for me in vs code. I installed spyder to try it. When I run my script I get

```
from gekko import GEKKO
```

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'gekko'

then I type

> py -m pip install gekko

and get

Requirement already satisfied: gekko in c:\python310\lib\site-packages (1.0.6)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.8 in c:\program files\spyder\pkgs (from gekko) (1.24.2)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I solve the - ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'gekko', in spyder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69186436/how-do-i-solve-the-modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-gekko-in-spyder)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Your youtube videos are great. I always watch them first. However the post you reference did not help me. I un-installed spyder, then installed anaconda, then re-installed spyder but I have the same problem.

Comment: Here is the message I get from the anaconda prompt >pip install gekko
Requirement already satisfied: gekko in c:\users\dalefinn\appdata\local\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (1.0.6)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.8 in c:\users\dalefinn\appdata\local\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from gekko) (1.23.5)

(base) C:\Users\dalefinn>

Comment: and from the console ...

Comment: Python 3.11.3 | packaged by conda-forge | (main, Apr  6 2023, 08:50:54) [MSC v.1934 64 bit (AMD64)]

IPython 8.13.2 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.

runfile('C:/Users/dalefinn/.spyder-py3/temp.py', wdir='C:/Users/dalefinn/.spyder-py3')
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File ~\AppData\Local\anaconda3\envs\spyder-env\Lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\py3compat.py:356 in compat_exec
    exec(code, globals, locals)

  File c:\users\dalefinn\.spyder-py3\temp.py:3
    from gekko import GEKKO

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'gekko'

Answer (score 0):

The version of Python `py` used for `pip install gekko` is different than the version of Python used by Spyder. One way to locate the Python path is to run this script from Spyder:

```py
import sys
print(sys.path)
```

This shows the Python directories included in the default search path for the libraries such as `gekko` and other directories needed to run:

**Anaconda Example Path Information**

```
['', 'C:\\Users\\user\\anaconda3\\python39.zip', 
 'C:\\Users\\user\\anaconda3\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Users\\user\\anaconda3\\lib',
 'C:\\Users\\user\\anaconda3',
 'C:\\Users\\user\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages', 
 'C:\\Users\\user\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\win32', 
 'C:\\Users\\user\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\win32\\lib', 
 'C:\\Users\\user\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\Pythonwin']
```

With the correct `pip` install, the `gekko` library is located in the `site-packages` directory. To correctly install `gekko` for this distribution, use:

```bash
C:\\Users\\user\\anaconda3\python.exe -m pip install gekko
```

**Another Python Distribution**

```
['', 'C:\\Users\\user\\Python311\\python311.zip',
 'C:\\Users\\user\\Python311\\Lib',
 'C:\\Users\\user\\Python311\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Users\\user\\Python311',
 'C:\\Users\\user\\Python311\\Lib\\site-packages']
```

The `gekko` library should be located in the `site-packages` directory. To correctly install `gekko` for this distribution, use:

```bash
C:\\Users\\user\\Python311\python.exe -m pip install gekko
```

**Easy Method, Not Recommended**

Although not recommended, another way to install `gekko` for Spyder, Jupyter Notebook, VSCode or other IDE is to pip install from a Python script.

```py
from pip._internal import main as pipmain
pipmain(['install','gekko'])
```

A more comprehensive guide to Python package management, including virtual environments, is on [this course website](https://apmonitor.com/dde/index.php/Main/InstallPythonPackages).

Comment: I ran the path script you show above, installed from there, and spyder finds gekko now. Thanks!